# Slice line of words on every <br>

Tags: javascript

This is text

```
1   firstWord   100    0        5   firstWord   
2   secondWord  100    0        5   secondWord  
3   thirdWord   0      0        0   thirdWord
```

My code do this

```
1   firstWord   100
```

I would like this

```
1   firstWord   100
2   secondWord  100
3   thirdWord   0
```

This is my code

```
response.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br>")
    .replace(/\s+/g, 'space')
    .split("space").slice(0, 3)
    .join("space");
```

This code deletes everything in the line starting 4th space.

How can I make it work on every break? Breaks are created in this part:

```
(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br>")
```

Comment: This code creates line in a plain text, then it replaces ' ' spaces with actual word 'space' just to make it moire clear. Then it deletes everything except first 3 words. But i would like to delete it on every new line.

Comment: Does every line have the exact same number of elements?

Comment: same number of elemets but different number of length, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it this way...

```js
var str = "1 firstWord 100 0 5 firstWord\n2 secondWord 100 0 5 secondWord\n3 thirdWord 0 0 0 thirdWord"
var results = str.match(/^((?:\S+\s+){2}\S+)/gmi);

var output = "";
if (results !== null) {
 results.forEach(function(element,index) {
   output += element + " <br/>";
  });
  document.write(output);
}
```

or something similar to your solution:

```
var arr = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br>").replace(/\s+/gm, 'space').split('<br>');

arr.forEach(function(element,index,array){
  array[index] = element.split('space').splice(0,3).join(' ');
});
```